# Questions around productionizing a crawler + scraper + index pipeline

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb

We're building a pipeline that crawls + scrapes certain kinds of webpages from the web (using various scraping libraries), and indexing them for search.

For the crawling / scraping part:

1. Run crawling over top level domains we care about.
2. Add URL (primary key) + metadata (json value) into a dynamoDB table.
3. Add scraped content into S3, and store a pointer to the file in the aforementioned metadata in dynamodb.

Now, we need to get the information into our ElasticSearch index. There are two high level requirements for this process:

1. New entries that are found need to be sent to the index.
2. Updates to existing entries (i.e. the metadata, or raw content in S3) need to update the index.

Couple of ways I thought about doing this:

- For (1) above, we can have a new entry trigger a lambda, and that would add a new document to the index in the elasticsearch table.
- For (2) above, we can have a job that runs through the entire table (say once a week), and re-ingests everything. (We can even get rid of (1) then.
- Alternate for (2) - when we run the update, we trigger a lambda and do the real-time update.

Questions:

1. Thoughts on URL being a primary key in DynamoDB? Will we get into hot partitioning issues? Also, if we store only the URL, but have a different doc_id in elasticsearch, then how would we be able to update a document? Is the common pattern that the doc_id is also stored in the dynamoDB table?
2. Pattern-wise, does this seem like a reasonable design for a scaled crawling, scraping, and indexing system? Any visible pitfalls?
3. Thoughts on the two implementation options for (2)? If "real-time" isn't much of a need, a periodic re-index job seems easier to setup, but I worry that full table scans on dynamoDB is expensive? (Cost-wise / may cause the DB to get hot)? Also, it will likely send a lot of update requests to the index, even on entries that don't need to be updated. Only way I can imagine combatting this is if there was a way to detect whether the entry was actually updated? (Maybe that's an argument for using a real-time update approach).

Appreciate the feedback, thanks!

Comment: You're looking at DynamoDB as the bottleneck? DynamoDB just has to hold a URL and some metadata about each page. It has the easiest job. Your challenges will be on scaling up the ElasticSearch side and being smart with the crawl logic.

Comment: Thanks @hunterhacker - are you suggesting that ElasticSearch is responsible for doing the page crawling? I was intending to do this separate from ElasticSearch so that other consumers can view the scraped content. And what scaling challenges are you referring to there (Like parallelization in scraping?)? And what do you mean by "smart with the crawl logic" (is it smart in terms of when to scrape? The per-site scraping logic itself? etc).

Comment: I don’t know your requirements but this stuff gets hard to do well at scale. The DynamoDB part tho is trivial compared to the rest.